Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "" does not exist in ""
I'm developing my own mvc and I just ran into this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "App\Core\Controller\ErrorController" does not exist in ...lib/core/Router/mvcRouter.php on line 146"
The index.php contains the autoloader:
{...}
function autoload( string $object ) {
    $split = explode( '\\', $object );
    $className = end( $split );
    $file = $className . '.php';

    echo "namespace: $object -> file: $file";
/*
output:
...
namespace: App\Core\Controller\ErrorController -> file: ErrorController.php
*/
    require_once $file;
}

spl_autoload_register( 'autoload' );
{...}

az mvcRouter.php 146 sora:
$reflector = new ReflectionClass( $this->controller );

In ErrorController.php:
<?php
namespace App\Core\Controller;

use Lib\Core\Application\ApplicationController;

class ErrorController extends ApplicationController {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function defaultAction() {
        echo "Error!";
    }
}

According to the output, the file and namespace are there, when you want to call them, they don't... Calling another Controller (e.g. App\Core\Controller\IndexController) works perfectly.
I compared the structure of the files, and everything is correct.
Thanks in advance for your help!

To help debug this I would start with using absolute paths. The statement require_once $file; does not actually mean "load this file from the current directory", but instead instructs PHP to first scan the global include path, and if that fails then use the CWD. The latter, however, can also not always be what you expect. As such, I'd recommend defining a global constant such as APP_ROOT that points to your true root, and build paths from that. Then in your auto load you can log "attempting to load $file` and see the full absolute path that it is trying to use.

The absolute paths of the files are added (the arrays contain the absolute paths of the directories):
$systemDir = array_merge( $classDir, $appCoreDir, $appUserDir, $appPluginDir );
foreach ( $systemDir as $cd ) {
    $reservedPath = get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $cd;
    set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $cd );
}
Currently, only the ErrorController is not found, other files read from here are also found.

Just to try something, can you manually try require_once on your ErrorController, using the absolute path. Leave the autoloader alone, just add this somewhere right before you expect it to be used.
